# Refresh Page Auto

Tags: php

How To auto refresh index (Php Page) or any , after update or insert data to (TABLE) mysql database ? the best example : Gmail (googlemail) . in gmail auto refresh page(inbox) after received new email.

Comment: There are several ways to refresh a page. You need to explain in more detail what kind of operation you are doing and whether you can use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail uses Comet ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))). It is more advanced ajax, so I recommend, if you haven't, you should read more about ajax.

If you want more detailed answer, I think you should better describe what's your situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
echo "Watch the page reload itself in 10 seconds!";
```